# Recursive CTE stop condition for loops

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need to iterate a graph with loops using the recursive CTE.

The problem is the *loop* part.

I want if there are loops, then the shortest path to be selected.
This basically means ignoring the loops because the recursion is "width first".

The example below shows the returned data:

The problem is the commented out `INSERT` statement that creates a loop.
With it uncommented, obviously, the query will never finish.

What I need is to return the same data as it would be without the loop.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS edges;

CREATE TABLE edges(
  src integer,
  dst integer,
  data integer
);

INSERT INTO edges VALUES (1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO edges VALUES (2, 3, 1);
--INSERT INTO edges VALUES (3, 2, 1);  -- This entry creates a loop
INSERT INTO edges VALUES (1, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO edges VALUES (4, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO edges VALUES (5, 2, 1);

INSERT INTO edges VALUES (1, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO edges VALUES (4, 5, 2);
INSERT INTO edges VALUES (4, 6, 2);


WITH RECURSIVE paths AS (
  -- For simplicity assume node 1 is the start
  -- we'll have two starting nodes for data = 1 and 2
  SELECT DISTINCT
    src           as node
    , data        as data
    , 0           as depth
    , src::text   as path
  FROM edges
  WHERE
    src = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DISTINCT
    edges.dst
    , edges.data
    , depth + 1
    , paths.path || '->' || edges.dst::text
  FROM paths
    JOIN edges ON edges.src = paths.node AND edges.data = paths.data
    -- AND eliminate loops?
)

SELECT * FROM paths;
```

Returning:

```
 node | data | depth |     path      
------+------+-------+---------------
    1 |    1 |     0 | 1
    1 |    2 |     0 | 1
    2 |    1 |     1 | 1->2
    4 |    1 |     1 | 1->4
    4 |    2 |     1 | 1->4
    3 |    1 |     2 | 1->2->3
    5 |    2 |     2 | 1->4->5
    6 |    2 |     2 | 1->4->6
    5 |    1 |     2 | 1->4->5
    2 |    1 |     3 | 1->4->5->2
    3 |    1 |     4 | 1->4->5->2->3
(11 rows)
```

Comment: Shortest-path traversal of a directed cyclic graph with a recursive CTE. Intriguing. A quick search finds lots written about this topic already...

Comment: Thanks for removing the duplicate post and for an interesting one here; +1, will play with this if I get the time.

Comment: I already have the answer (which is pretty obvious and simple), but won't provide it here yet :) Want to see other options.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH RECURSIVE paths AS (
    -- For simplicity assume node 1 is the start
    -- we'll have two starting nodes for data = 1 and 2
    SELECT DISTINCT
        src           as node
        , data        as data
        , 0           as depth
        , src::text   as path
        , ''          as edgeAdded   
    FROM edges
    WHERE
        src = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT
        edges.dst
        , edges.data
        , depth + 1
        , paths.path || '->' || edges.dst::text
        , edges.src::text || '->' || edges.dst::text
    FROM paths
    JOIN edges ON edges.src = paths.node AND edges.data = paths.data
    AND NOT paths.path LIKE '%' || edges.dst::text || '%' 
        -- AND eliminate loops?
)
SELECT * FROM paths;
```

Here with the condition `AND NOT paths.path LIKE '%' || edges.dst::text || '%'` we are avoiding back edges which would lead to a loop.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/086ee/1

Comment: That's approximately the solution I have. Except yours will still never finish with the loop into the starting node. But that's easy to fix. I'll wait for other options for the solution before accepting though.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of handling cycles is building an array on the way and checking if element already exist in it:

```
WITH RECURSIVE paths AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    src           as node
    , data        as data
    , 0           as depth
    , src::text   as path
    , false       as is_cycle
    , ARRAY[src]  as path_array
  FROM edges
  WHERE src IN (1,2)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT
    edges.dst
    , edges.data
    , depth + 1
    , paths.path || '->' || edges.dst::text
    , dst = ANY(path_array)
    , path_array  || dst
  FROM paths
  JOIN edges 
    ON edges.src = paths.node 
    AND edges.data = paths.data
    AND NOT is_cycle
)
SELECT * FROM paths;
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
| node  | data  | depth  |       path        | is_cycle  |  path_array   |
+-------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
|    1  |    1  |     0  | 1                 | f         | {1}           |
|    1  |    2  |     0  | 1                 | f         | {1}           |
|    2  |    1  |     0  | 2                 | f         | {2}           |
|    2  |    1  |     1  | 1->2              | f         | {1,2}         |
|    3  |    1  |     1  | 2->3              | f         | {2,3}         |
|    4  |    1  |     1  | 1->4              | f         | {1,4}         |
|    4  |    2  |     1  | 1->4              | f         | {1,4}         |
|    2  |    1  |     2  | 2->3->2           | t         | {2,3,2}       |
|    3  |    1  |     2  | 1->2->3           | f         | {1,2,3}       |
|    5  |    1  |     2  | 1->4->5           | f         | {1,4,5}       |
|    5  |    2  |     2  | 1->4->5           | f         | {1,4,5}       |
|    6  |    2  |     2  | 1->4->6           | f         | {1,4,6}       |
|    2  |    1  |     3  | 1->2->3->2        | t         | {1,2,3,2}     |
|    2  |    1  |     3  | 1->4->5->2        | f         | {1,4,5,2}     |
|    3  |    1  |     4  | 1->4->5->2->3     | f         | {1,4,5,2,3}   |
|    2  |    1  |     5  | 1->4->5->2->3->2  | t         | {1,4,5,2,3,2} |
+-------+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dfe8858352afad6411609d157d3fe85e)**

---

**PostgreSQL 14 will extend recursive cte with two new clauses `SEARCH` and `CYCLE`**:

> [Cycle Detection](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE)
>
> ```
> CYCLE id SET is_cycle TO true DEFAULT false USING path
> ```
>
> The CYCLE clause specifies first the list of columns to track for cycle detection, then a column name that will show whether a cycle has been detected, then two values to use in that column for the yes and no cases, and finally the name of another column that will track the path. The cycle and path columns will implicitly be added to the output rows of the CTE.

Here demo using the same syntax(Oracle):

```
WITH paths(node, data,depth,path) AS (
  SELECT
    src           as node
    , data        as data
    , 0           as depth
    , TO_CHAR(src)as path
  FROM edges
  WHERE src IN (1,2)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    edges.dst
    , edges.data
    , depth + 1
    , paths.path || '->' || edges.dst
  FROM paths
  JOIN edges 
    ON edges.src = paths.node 
    AND edges.data = paths.data
) CYCLE node SET cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM paths;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b8db93a2e8382a255c2f614818d7c31)**