# Detect cycles using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I want to detect potential cycles in a hierarchy. I have three tables, each have one parent, and one child column:

[image: Table1's parents are Table2's children and Table2's parents are Table3's children]

Table1 contains some nodes (in column child) and their parents (in column parent); Table2 contains all the parents of Table1 (in column child) and their parents (in column parent), and so on.

For example if A is a child of B, and B is a child of C and C is a child of A, then I have a cycle.

Is it possible to detect the cycles using sql commands?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Postgres. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What so you mean by cycles? Will you be able to elobrate

Comment: Do you want to detect cycles _between_ the tables (if yes, why isn't this stored in a single table?) Or just in one table? [edit] your question and add the **real** definition of the tables (as `create table` statements), some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: For example if A is a child of B, and B is a child of C and C is a child of A, then I have a cycle.

Comment: I stored them in separate tables because I thought it might make the cycle detection process easier. That's why!

Comment: Don't de-normalize your model just because you _think_ it would make things easier.

Comment: If I dump all the parent-child relationships in one table, is there a way I can detect the cycles?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671612/prevent-and-or-detect-cycles-in-postgres or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194553/detecting-cycles-in-a-recursive-query

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739150/to-find-infinite-recursive-loop-in-cte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with arbitrary depth.

Store all your relationships in one table:

```
   Table t
Parent | Child
------ | -----
B      | A
C      | B
A      | C
E      | D
F      | E
```

Then you can use this [`WITH RECURSIVE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) query to find cycles:

```
WITH RECURSIVE working(parent, last_visited, already_visited, cycle_detected) AS (
  SELECT parent, child, ARRAY[parent], false FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.parent, t.child, already_visited || t.parent, t.parent = ANY(already_visited)
  FROM t
  JOIN working ON working.last_visited = t.parent
  WHERE NOT cycle_detected
)
SELECT parent, already_visited FROM working WHERE cycle_detected
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/05914/1)

It will give you the `parent`s that are part of a cycle, and also the cycle they are in:

```
A | A,C,B,A
B | B,A,C,B
C | C,B,A,C
```

It works like this (because that is what the keyword `RECURSIVE` instructs Postgres to do):

1. Run the first `SELECT`, selecting all entries from table `t` and placing them in a temporary table named `working`.
2. Then run the second `SELECT`, joining the `working` table with table `t` to find the children of each entry. Those children are added to the array of already seen children.
3. Now run the second `SELECT` again and again, as long as entries are added to the `working` table.
4. A cycle is detected when one of the entries visits a child that it has visited before (`t.parent = ANY(already_visited)`) in this case `cycle_detected` is set to true and no more children are added to the entry.

Comment: Thank you for the great stuff and for your comprehensive explanation. Very useful.

Comment: Also, here's the official Postgres docs that I believe do a great job of explaining how the RECURSIVE queries work.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-SELECT

Comment: Soon PostgreSQL will support [`CYCLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66050763/5070879) clause which simplify the process

Answer (score 2):

The way you have structured your tables right now, the following SQL should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.child = Table2.parent
INNER JOIN Table3 on Table2.child = Table3.parent
WHERE Table1.parent = Table3.child;
```

Comment: If your query returns nothing, it means there is no cycles, right?

Comment: Yes. It should return all existing cycles, so if it returns nothing, then there are no cycles.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are very strange references between tables in your task. Yet it is my approach to check existing loop.

Example for table1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_table1_check() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  PERFORM 1 FROM table2
    JOIN table3 ON table3.parent=table2.child
  WHERE table2.parent=NEW.child AND table3.child=NEW.parent
  LIMIT 1;
  IF FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Found recursive loop!';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_check BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_table1_check();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not familiar with plpgsql. I will study your code.